# Not able to SSH to new command line created instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools, aws-cli

I'm creating a new instance by using the following command,

`ec2-run-instances   --key "xxxx keypair"   --instance-type t1.micro   --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate   --user-data-file myscript.sh   $ami_id`

And my AMI is **bitnami default AMI**

after I launch the instance, used the following code from my older instance to connect new instance,

`ssh -i xxx_yyy.pem bitnami@xxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

And I can't connect this, there is no response from server,

Can anyone please help me in this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error msg you are getting while you are trying to connect ? Check for the correct fqdn of the server.

Comment: run **`ssh -vvv -i xxx_yyy.pem bitnami@xxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`** and then post the output.

Comment: I found the issue, my security group did't allow me to connect with ssh, have created own security group with ssh enabled and then launched the instance fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your help Rajarshi and slayedbylucifer.

Answer (score 1):

Typical things to check when trying to connect to an EC2 instance:

**Security Groups**
Check that at least one of the Security Groups associated with the instance has port 22 (SSH) or port 3389 (RDP) open to your source IP range (eg a specific IP address 54.87.23.11/32, or the whole world 0.0.0.0/0 -- but the latter is very poor security practice). Security Groups are stateful, so you only need to open **Inbound** access and the return path will automatically work.

**Public IP Address**
Confirm that you are using a Public IP address associated with the instance. This can either be assigned at instance launch (which will allocate a random IP address from a pool) or can be assigned as an Elastic IP Address (which is a static IP address that you can assign assign to any instance and you keep it until you release it back to AWS).

**Public Subnet / Routing**
Confirm that your instance is in a "Public" VPC Subnet. This means that the Route Table associated with the Subnet has a route through an Internet Gateway.

**AMI Operating System**
I've seen situations where people try to SSH to a Windows instance, or RDP to a Linux instance, so also check that you launched the correct AMI for your expected operating system.